# Should I use a model created in Multiple Linear Regression and apply randomForest to it?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, random-forest

Since Random Forest regressor does not give summary(regressor) adjusted r squared values  can I build my model in Multiple Linear Regression and then apply randomForest for better R Squared.

Comment: If you're looking to improve on estimated accuracy, have a look at the relaimpo package in R. This is an average-over-orderings method of evaluating R2. If you're instead looking for a better predictive fit, then I'd probably not worry about R2 and instead use a method of cross validation.

Comment: Do you look for a way to measure RSQ for random Forest regression?

Comment: yes exactly that is what I am looking for

Comment: Then you should think of renaming your question to better fit the core of this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `mlr::measureRSQ` to compute R-squared meaures for randomForest objects. here is a reproducible example:

```
train <- ggplot2::diamonds[1:100,]
valid <- ggplot2::diamonds[101:200, ]

rf <- randomForest::randomForest(price~., data = train)
pred <- predict(rf, valid)
truth <- valid$price
mlr::measureRSQ(truth = truth, 
                response = pred)
```